# Scene transition removes everything

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-view, android-transitions

I am trying to integrate the [Draggable panel library](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel) with my video playing project, and so far its been working great for my needs.

First I set it up so that DraggablePanel is always in my view Root, so that it covers the whole screen when maximized.

But now I want to do a nice transition from the thumbnail to the Video window, like Youtube does. I have tried this:

```
public static void launch(TransitionableClass t,
                          AppCompatActivity activity,
                          Fragment bottomFragment,
                          ViewGroup container,
                          View iv,
                          String transitionName,
                          String url) {
    DraggableVideoPanel draggableVideoPanel = new DraggableVideoPanel(activity.getApplicationContext());
    draggableVideoPanel.setFragmentManager(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    draggableVideoPanel.setBottomFragment(bottomFragment);

    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    activity.getResources().getValue(R.dimen.x_scale_factor, typedValue, true);
    float xScaleFactor = typedValue.getFloat();
    typedValue = new TypedValue();
    activity.getResources().getValue(R.dimen.y_scale_factor, typedValue, true);
    float yScaleFactor = typedValue.getFloat();



    draggableVideoPanel.setXScaleFactor(xScaleFactor);
    draggableVideoPanel.setYScaleFactor(yScaleFactor);
    draggableVideoPanel.setTopViewHeight(
            activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.top_fragment_height));
    draggableVideoPanel.setTopFragmentMarginRight(
            activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.top_fragment_margin));
    draggableVideoPanel.setTopFragmentMarginBottom(
            activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.top_fragment_margin));


    draggableVideoPanel.initializeView();
    draggableVideoPanel.maximize();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        iv.setTransitionName(transitionName);
        draggableVideoPanel.mCoverView.setTransitionName(transitionName);


        Transition shared = t.inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move);
        shared.addTarget(transitionName);
        shared.setDuration(200);

        Transition fade = t.inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade);
        fade.excludeTarget(transitionName, true);
        fade.setDuration(200);

        TransitionSet transitionSet = new TransitionSet();

        transitionSet.addTransition(fade).addTransition(shared);

        Scene scene = new Scene(container, draggableVideoPanel);
        draggableVideoPanel.mCoverView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);

        TransitionManager.go(scene, transitionSet);
    }

}
```

So i create a move transition from the two shared views and then a fade for the rest. this piece of code I took from [here](https://github.com/eugenkiss/MaterialEverywhere/commit/53b6ddcd22f40e06b11a06b9c7613a1e8b13ffe5)

Now whithout the transition the DraggablePanel used to work just fine, but now by using Transitions I got this:

[http://i.imgur.com/2aPxDJX.mp4](https://i.imgur.com/2aPxDJX.mp4)

So it looks like somehow the transition created a white background. Using layout inspector I found out that actually all elements from the window were actually removed from the scene when applying the transition.

How can I prevent this? How can I do a transition between views in my app?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scene scene = new Scene(container, draggableVideoPanel);
```

You are using this constructor: [`Scene (ViewGroup sceneRoot, View layout)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Scene.html#Scene(android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.view.View)):

> Constructs a Scene which, when entered, **will remove any children from the sceneRoot** container and add the layout object as a new child of that container.

As stated in the docs, this `Scene` results in removing everything in the `container` except for `draggableVideoPanel`.

What you want is [`TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(ViewGroup sceneRoot, Transition transition)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html#beginDelayedTransition(android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.transition.Transition)).

Comment: But can I do a shared element transition with this? Just tried but it did not work

Comment: Yes, you can. In the code perform `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(viewGroup, transition);` And below of this line perform changes to the layout that you want to reposition, e.g.; `draggableVideoPanel.setX(0);`. `Transitions API` will count the delta and apply `transition`. Note, `draggableVideoPanel` should be a child of `viewGroup`.

Comment: you are right it does work but for some reason the transition is not working as expected https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vM__d-4xFv8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: The video you shared is private.

Comment: sorry try again pleasew

Comment: It seems to me, that you have passed an incorrect first parameter to the `beginDelayedTransition()`. Pass the topmost root view, so that Transitions API animates everything that has been changed. Currently you are passing some child `ViewGroup`, that's why `TransitionManager` animates changes only within that `ViewGroup`.

Comment: I am passing the DrawerLayout, which is the topmost viewgroup in my layout. This DrawerLayout belongs to the activity Layout, I ma working within a Fragment, but this transition worked like this when using the Scene transition